# Find the inverse of the integral transform $ S_n\{f\}=\int_{0}^1f(x)x^{n}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

Let $S$ denote the integral transform that maps every function $f$ integrable on (0,1) to a sequence $\left(S_n\{f\}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$:
$$S:f\mapsto \left(S_n\{f\}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\text{ defined by: } S_n\{f\}=\int_{0}^1f(x)x^{n}dx$$

Note that it's quite similar to the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform), whose expression is $$M\{f\}(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)x^{s-1}dx$$
the differences being that for $S$ the integration is over $(0,1)$ instead of the whole real axis, and the transformed function is taken only on the integers instead of the real numbers so that it defines a sequence and not a proper function.

My question is, wether it is possible to determine under what conditions $S$ is injective, and more importantly **an expression if its inverse transform $S^{-1}$ that would enable us to recover $f$ from the sequence $S_n\{f\}$.**

In the case of the Mellin transform, we know that under certain [conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem) the inverse Mellin transform is defined and thus we can recover the original function from its transformed with the formula:

$$M^{-1}\{\varphi\}(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\varphi(s)x^{-s}ds$$

Because of the similarities between $S$ and the Mellin transform, I thought this might help, but it didn't lead me anywhere so far.

In case $S^{-1}$ cannot be expressed explicitely, then I'd like to study the case where of a continuous variable $s$ instead of a discrete variable $n$ (i.e $S$ maps a function to another function, and not a sequence):

$$S'\{f\}(s)=\int_{0}^1f(x)x^{s}dx$$

Of course, the invertibility of $S$ and $S'$ are not equivalent.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It is injective but I don 't think you can  invert it explicitly.

Comment: I'm curious, how can you tell it is injective ?

Comment: Weierstrass approximation combined with the fact that any integrable function can be approximated in $L^{1}$ norm by continuous functions proves that the map is injective.

Comment: Thank you. And in the case where the variable is continuous and not discrete (see my edit), would it still be injective ? Because I can't imagine both $S$ and $S'$ be injective at the same time..

Comment: Injectivity of $S$ implies injectivity of $S'$.

Comment: I suggest you look into the topic of orthogonal polynomials transforms for the first transform as that topic is well studied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting $x=e^{-t}$,

$$ S_n\{f\} = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)x^n\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}f(e^{-t})e^{-t}e^{-nt}\,dt = \mathcal{L}(f(e^{-t})e^{-t})(n) $$
hence the inverse transform is achieved through

1. an application of $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ (inverse Laplace transform)
2. a replacement of the variable with $-\log s$
3. a division by $s$.

If only the values of $S_n\{f\}$ for natural $n$s are known, one may exploit the fact that 
$$ f(x)\stackrel{L^2(0,1)}{=} \sum_{n\geq 0} \left((2n+1)\int_{0}^{1}f(x)P_n(2x-1)\,dx\right)P_n(2x-1)$$
where $P_n(2x-1)$ is a shifted Legendre polynomial,
$$ P_n(2x-1)=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}(-x)^k = \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-x)^n.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This might be a dumb question but, $S_n\{f\}$ is a sequence, so how can you compute the inverse Laplace transform of a sequence ? Is it related to the Z-transform ?

Comment: @HarmonicSun: well, $S_n\{f\}$ is defined for real $n$s too, so there is no need of the Z-transform.

Comment: You are right, but as Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out in a comment, even if we let $n$ take only integers value (so that $S\{f\}$ is a sequence and not a function), it's still injective so there has to be an inverse who takes a sequence as an input, and this is what I'm more specifically interested about.

For example, say we have a given sequence $\left(u_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, and want to find the only $f$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, S_n\{f\}=u_n...$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Since the OP asks about the evaluation only at natural numbers,  the answer is the orthogonal polynomials, not inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. However, one thing bugs me : the Fourier-Legendre decomposition of $f$ that you stated converges with respect to the $L^2(0,1)$ norm, that doesn't imply pointwise convergence. Without pointwise convergence, this is not a proper equality that holds $\forall x\in(0,1)$, and thus I don't see how it's exploitable to find $S^{-1}$...