# Question about the sequence of moments of a continuous function

Tags: integration, asymptotics, laplace-transform

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Consider for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ :

> $$M_n(f)=\int_0^1t^n\,f(t)\,dt$$

It is easy to see that the sequence $\left(M_n(f)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$.

But is it possible to choose $f$ in such a way that :

> $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,M_n(f)=e^{-\lambda n^2}$$

where $\lambda$ is some positive constant ?

It can be seen that such a function could not be positive and would necessarily verify $f(1)=0$, but I wasn't able to get much more than that ...

Any hint would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry to bother, but why the sequence converges to zero?

Comment: Awww, sorry, got it, use Cauchy Schwarz which guaranties convergence to zero with  $O\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) $ if $f$ is $\mathscr{L}^2$ on $[0,1]$

Comment: You could simply use the modulus inequality : $\vert\int_0^1t^nf(t)\,dt\vert\leqslant\int_0^1t^n\vert f(t)\vert\,dt\leqslant\Vert f\Vert_\infty/(n+1)$

Comment: Is there a reason why you presume this is true?  Maybe some context would help in finding a solution, or so I've been told?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3310229/512032

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer.

Note that the set of polynomials is dense in $L^2([0,1])$. Hence there exists a complete orthogonal system in $L^2([0,1])$ 
$$p_0(t),p_1(t),...,p_n(t),...$$
consisting of polynomials. Note that $p_n(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Suppose that
$$p_n(t) = c(n)_n t^n + ... + c(n)_1t + c(n)_0$$
where $c(n)_i\in \mathbb{R}$ and $c(n)_n\neq 0$.

Fix $f\in L^2([0,1])$. We have
$$A_n(f) = \int^1_0p_n(t)f(t)dt = c(n)_n\cdot M_n(f) + ... + c(n)_1\cdot M_1(f) + c(n)_0\cdot M_0(f)$$
for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. On the other hand we know from the theory of Hilbert spaces that **the only constraint** on the sequence of numbers $\{A_n(f)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is

$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n(f)^2 < +\infty$$

Thus if you calculate (recursively, by means of Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization) the sequence $\{p_n(t)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, then you may check if there exists $f\in L^2([0,1])$ such that
$$M_n(f) = e^{-\lambda n^2}$$
simply by calculating $\{A_n(f)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and checking that its $l_2$-norm is finite. I don't know, if this is tractable.